# DataSource Restriction in Sitecore MultiSite

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I have a multisite solution 
 [Content
       |---Site1
       |        |---Home1
       |
       |---Site2
                |---Home2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Je3.png)

where Home1 item of Site1 and Home2 item of Site2 are using same template HomeTemplate.
I have a multilist in HomeTemplate in which I have to provide a datasource in such a way that, In Home1 item, multilist is filled with content of Site1 and In Home2 item, multilist is filled with content of Site2 (as per the Site).
Is this possible using Sitecore queries or there is other way to do it?

Answer (score 7):

You can have a query string like a data source for your multilist field

query:./../*

or

query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='HomeTemplate']/../*

Please check next link for more details source query of a field

http://blog.arkesystems.com/post/2011/03/22/Sitecore-Using-the-Source-Property.aspx